# $S^2 \times S^2$ is diffeomophic to $G_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$

Tags: differential-topology

$G_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$ is the Grassmannian manifold of two-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$. I would like a detailed proof. Can it be done explicitly? I mean, showing the map and checking its differentiability using charts?

Comment: What is $G_2(\mathbb R^4)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something along the lines of what follows should work. I haven't yet checked smoothness (but everything *is* smooth), and there is a problem towards the end that prevents me from reaching a conclusion.

---

Consider the [Stiefel manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold) $V_2(\Bbb R^4)$ of orthonormal $2$ frames, i.e. of pairs of vectors $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^4$such that $x\cdot y=0$ and $|x|=|y|=1$. The group $O(2)$ of real orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrices acts on $V_2(\Bbb R^4)$ by $$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\cdot(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy)$$
and the orbit of a point $(x,y)\in V_2(\Bbb R^4)$ under this action is the collection of all orthonormal bases of $\operatorname{Vect}(x,y)=\Bbb R x\oplus \Bbb R y$. Thus the canonical map
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{Vect}:&V_2(\Bbb R^4)\to G_2(\Bbb R^4)\\ & (x,y)\mapsto\operatorname{Vect}(x,y)\end{align}$$
of which smoothness would have to be checked (which it is), gives rise to a diffeomorphism
$$O(2)\backslash V_2(\Bbb R^4)\xrightarrow{~\sim~}G_2(\Bbb R^4)$$
On the other hand, let us consider $\Bbb R^4=\Bbb C^2$ through $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto(x_1+ix_2,x_3+ix_4)$ and the map
$$\begin{align} \phi :&V_2(\Bbb R^4)\to\mathrm{P}^1(\Bbb C)\times\mathrm{P}^1(\Bbb C)\\&(x,x')\mapsto (\Bbb C x,\Bbb Cx')\end{align}$$
The complex projective line $\mathrm{P}^1(\Bbb C)$ is diffeomorphic to the two sphere $S^2$, so we may consider that $\phi$ maps to $S^2\times S^2$. Let us show that this map is onto. Let $l=\Bbb C x$ and $l'$ be two complex lines $\subset\Bbb C^2$ (i.e. $\in\mathrm{P}^1(\Bbb C)$). Then $l'\cap x^{\perp}\neq 0$, since $l'$ has real dimension $2$ and $x^{\perp}$ has real dimension $3$, and everything happens inside $\Bbb C^2$ which has real dimension $4$. Let $x'\in l'\cap x^{\perp}$ be of unit length, then $l'=\Bbb Cx'$ and $(l,l')=\phi(x,x')$.

Now let us solve (for $(x,x')\in V_2(\Bbb R^4)$) the equation $\phi(x,x')=(l,l')=\phi(x_0,x'_0)$. If $(x,x')\in V_2(\Bbb R^4)$ satisfy $\phi(x,x')=\phi(x_0,x'_0)$, then there exists $z=e^{i\theta},z'=e^{i\theta'}\in S^1$ (i.e. complex numbers of module one) with $x=zx_0$ and $x'=z'x'_0$, but we must also have $x\cdot x'=0(=x_0\cdot x'_0)$.

For $x_0=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb R^4\longleftrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}X_1\\X_2\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb C^2$ and $x'_0=\begin{pmatrix}x_1'\\x_2'\\x_3'\\x_4'\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb R^4\longleftrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}X_1'\\X_2'\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb C^2$, $x=zx_0=\begin{pmatrix}zX_1\\zX_2\end{pmatrix}$, $x'=z'x'_0=\begin{pmatrix}z'X_1'\\z'X_2'\end{pmatrix}$ and $0=x_0\cdot x'_0=\mathrm{Re}(X_1\overline{X'_1})+\mathrm{Re}(X_2\overline{X'_2})=\mathrm{Re}(X_1\overline{X'_1}+X_2\overline{X'_2})$ while $$x\cdot x'=\mathrm{Re}(zX_1\overline{z'X'_1})+\mathrm{Re}(zX_2\overline{z'X'_2})=\mathrm{Re}\Big(e^{i(\theta-\theta')}(X_1\overline{X'_1}+X_2\overline{X'_2})\Big)$$

---

Here's where I run into a problem, because I'd like to conclude that $e^{i(\theta-\theta')}=\pm 1$, but for that I'd need $X_1\overline{X'_1}+X_2\overline{X'_2}=\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}X_1\\X_2\end{pmatrix}|\begin{pmatrix}X_1'\\X_2'\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle\neq 0$, i.e. $l$ not orthogonal to $l'$ in the hermitian space $\Bbb C^2$, which would force $z=\pm z'$ and would give a left action of $O(2)$ on $V_2(\Bbb R^4)$ whose orbits are exactly the fibers of $\phi$. This would give a diffeomorphism
$$O(2)\backslash V_2(\Bbb R^4)\xrightarrow{~\sim~}\mathrm{P}^1(\Bbb C)\times\mathrm{P}^1(\Bbb C)$$
Since $\mathrm{P}^1(\Bbb C)=S^2$ this would almost be enough, at least once we show that the two actions of $O(2)$ are conjugate.

---

To add a little more detail on the action of $O(2)$ on $V_2(\Bbb R^4=\Bbb C^2)$, I consider at the end, it is obtained from $O(2)=S^1\times\lbrace -1,+1\rbrace$ and $$(z,\pm 1)\cdot (x,x')=(zx,\pm zx')\;.$$

Comment: I think I might have a way around this problem if I use the quaternions and two ways of endowing $\Bbb H$ with a complex structure : that associated to $i$, and that associated to $j$. I'll come back to this question tonight. The problem with the above approach is that the complex lines are stable under $O(2)$, this problem should be avoided if I use two different complex structures.

Comment: I was trying to check the details of this and it seems to me that your map $\phi$ is not well-defined. (I can rotate $u,v$ before sending them to their complex span)... maybe I'm just missing something

Comment: The problem is that $S^2\times S^2$ is diffeomorphic to $G_2^+(\mathbb{R}^4)$, the Grassmannian of *oriented* $2$-planes, and not $G_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$. This is shown in various ways in other posts on this site.