# $S^2 \times S^2$ diffeomorphic to oriented $2$ dimensional vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

As the question title says, is the product of spheres $S^2 \times S^2$ diffeomorphic to the set of oriented $2$ dimensional vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 0):

$S^2\times S^2$ is the Grassmannian of $2$-planes in $R^4$, that is the set of oriented two planes of $R^4$ not of $R^2$.

See a proof here [$S^2 \times S^2$ is diffeomophic to $G_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650862/s2-times-s2-is-diffeomophic-to-g-2-mathbbr4)